# Fastest way to calculate the centroid of a set of coordinate tuples in python without numpy

Tags: python, performance

I've been working on a project that is incredibly time sensitive (that unfortunately has to be in python) and one of the functions that is used extensively is a function that calculates the centroid of a list of (x, y) tuples. To illustrate:

```
def centroid(*points):
    x_coords = [p[0] for p in points]
    y_coords = [p[1] for p in points]
    _len = len(points)
    centroid_x = sum(x_coords)/_len
    centroid_y = sum(y_coords)/_len
    return [centroid_x, centroid_y]
```

where

```
>>> centroid((0, 0), (10, 0), (10, 10), (0, 10))
[5, 5]
```

This function runs fairly quickly, the above example completing in an average of 1.49e-05 seconds on my system but I'm looking for the fastest way to calculate the centroid. Do you have any ideas?

One of the other solutions I had was to do the following (where `l` is the list of tuples):

```
map(len(l).__rtruediv__, map(sum, zip(*l)))
```

Which runs in between 1.01e-05 and 9.6e-06 seconds, but unfortunately converting to a list (by surrounding the whole statement in `list( ... )`) nearly *doubles* computation time.

EDIT: Suggestions are welcome in pure python BUT NOT numpy.

EDIT2: Just found out that if a separate variable is kept for the length of the list of tuples, then my above implementation with `map` runs reliably under 9.2e-06 seconds, but there's still the problem of converting back to a list.

EDIT3:

Now I'm only accepting answers in pure python, NOT in numpy (sorry to those that already answered in numpy!)

Comment: do you look for a pure python implementation? because numpy is really the thing to do this...

Comment: Seems like this may be a case of premature optimization, is the speed of this really slowing down your program significantly?

Comment: Updated the question to include this. I would love to see either implementations!

Comment: @F.J. maybe so, but I'm still interested in implementations of it. Believe it or not it is a significant performance hit when dealing with huge sets of coordinates (10,000+).

Comment: It's a lot less premature than most questions of this type :-) You've made measurements, and think this function occurs extensively. That counts for a lot.

Comment: Consuming the `map` with `tuple` rather than `list` will shave off a few nanoseconds.  But I think you're pretty close to the limit of how fast a pure-python implementation will go with the `map` method.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(100000, 2))
```

this here is fast

```
def centeroidnp(arr):
    length = arr.shape[0]
    sum_x = np.sum(arr[:, 0])
    sum_y = np.sum(arr[:, 1])
    return sum_x/length, sum_y/length

%timeit centeroidnp(data)
10000 loops, best of 3: 181 µs per loop
```

surprisingly, this is much slower:

```
%timeit data.mean(axis=0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.75 ms per loop
```

numpy seems very quick to me...

For completeness:

```
def centeroidpython(data):
    x, y = zip(*data)
    l = len(x)
    return sum(x) / l, sum(y) / l
#take the data conversion out to be fair!
data = list(tuple(i) for i in data)

%timeit centeroidpython(data)
10 loops, best of 3: 57 ms per loop
```

Comment: It makes sense to me as well that all these numpy implementations would and SHOULD be faster than the pure python implementation but my results have shown otherwise. I'll update the question to include some of my tests.

Comment: try to replicate with my exact function and data, and see if you get different results..., i will add my pure python solution. How do you time? because some timing methods are very inaccurate.

Comment: I time via python's `timeit` module, which I've been told in the past is one of the most accurate methods of timing in python. Is there a better method of testing for time?

Comment: Okay, nevermind, I actually was doing something wrong with my testing and the pure python implementation is MUCH slower than your numpy implementation, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Very small remark for the function centeroidnp() the output should be  sum_x/float(length), sum_y/ float(length)

Answer (score 9):

In Cartesian coordinates, the centroid is just the mean of the components:

```
data = ((0,0), (1,1), (2,2))
np.mean(data, axis=0)
>>> array([1., 1.])
```

Answer (score 5):

Just for completeness, I modified Retozi's function so it accepts a vector of any dimension:

```
def centeroidnp(arr):
    length, dim = arr.shape
    return np.array([np.sum(arr[:, i])/length for i in range(dim)])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a naive numpy implementation, I can't time here so I wonder how it does:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.asarray(points)
length = arr.shape[0]
sum_x = np.sum(arr[:, 0])
sum_y = np.sum(arr[:, 1])
return sum_x / length, sum_y / length
```

You pass the points to `centroid()` as separate parameters, that are then put into a single tuple with `*points`. It would be faster to just pass in a list or iterator with points.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or what but my tests show that this ran in a staggering 0.0001795993626296154 seconds.

Comment: that is the same runtime as the accepted answer @user3002473