# Find distance between a centroid and a point

Tags: python, nearest-neighbor, centroid

Let's say I have this list of a point' features `[3.5, 2.5, 7.5]` and the calculated centroid of a class - `0.700`

I have to find the Euclidean distance between the point and the centroid. And this is where I'm lost as the formula for Euclidean distance that I'm using is:

[image: dist = \sqrt{\left ( x_{1} - y_{1}\right )^2 + (x_2 - y_2)^2}]

```
def __euclidean(self, x, y):
    return sqrt(sum(pow(a - b, 2) for a, b in zip(x, y)))
```

In this case, the x variable is the list of features and the y variable is the value of the centroid - 0.7.
Am I missing something obvious?

Edit: I'm adding the algorithm I'm trying to implement as well as the formula for the centroid.

algorithm:
[image]

The input of Algorithm 1 are the training data, X = {x1, x2,...,xn}, the number of centroid neighbours k, the distance metric (Dist) to compute the similarity between points, and the target point p whose class will be estimated. The output is the radius that defines the neighbourhood around
the target point p.

centroid formula:

```
def __compute_centroid(self, points):
    sum_centroid = []
    for p in points:
        sum_centroid.append(sum(p))
    return (1 / len(points)) * sum(sum_centroid)
```

Comment: ?  Is your code producing an error?  What's the problem?

Comment: It's not clear, is your space 1D or 2D? I see only a 1D vector as your list of points

Comment: @mozway no, this is one point with 3 features (x1, x2, x3). My problem is that I don't have y1, y2, y3 as the centroid is just 0.7

Comment: @Him no errors just stuck on some logic

Comment: what does it even *mean* to find the distance between the 3D vector `x` and the 1D vector `y`?

Comment: Are you trying to calculate distance between point *in 3D space* and point *in 1D space*?

Comment: That's my problem exactly - I'll edit the question with the algorithm in a sec

Comment: You're getting a lot of questions because it's not clear how to interpret the distance between `[3.5, 2.5, 7.5]` (a vector) and `0.7` (a scalar). Assuming this problem has 3 features (as your example of a point suggests), your centroids should also have 3 elements. In other words, they should be 3D vectors. Once you have two 3-element vectors, you can compute the distance between them.

Comment: @kwinkunks It is confusing to me, so it's hard to explain it. I won't have any problems if my centroid was a 3-element vector but the formula I saw in the paper I'm trying to implement is the one I've pasted - it returns a singular value. I think the problem is there - in the calculation of the centroid.

Comment: If I had a 2-dimensional vector I would have been able to calculate the centroid as something like that -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/23021198/5486299

Comment: I think I get what's going on; see my answer. You are summing all your features — you need to take the average of each feature (column in X) independently. I used NumPy but I'm sure you can pick it up from there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the `compute_centroid` function.

For Cartesian coordinates, the centroid is at the mean of each coordinate computed independently of the others:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> points = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> centroid = np.mean(points, axis=0)
>>> centroid
array([2.5, 3.5, 4.5])
```

This is a 3-vector, so now you can compute the distance between it and another data point:

```
>>> q = np.array([7, 8, 9])
>>> np.linalg.norm(q - centroid)
7.794228634059948
```

(I think your Euclidean function works, but I didn't test it.)

Comment: Thank you so much! I've changed the compute_centroid function with your suggestion and left the Euclidean function as it was. It works perfectly! Thank you, again!

Comment: @A.L. consider upvoting the accepted answer